# Java: How can you generate a folder by importing a jar

Tags: java, jar, resources, directory, auto-generate

I made a framework that needs a resources folder including 2 other folders with specific names. Is there a way to generate them into the project by simply importing my jar? 
[image: Visual of the problem]

Comment: I don't think you can create the folders in the project just by importing the jar. But, you can access the folders inside the jar from the project. Does that help ?

Comment: Does that rewrite the folder or makes a copy? because its a global jar and  I need to put other kinds of resources in it for each project.

Answer (score 0):

If a `.jar` is on the classpath, then its resource folders should automatically be available to the JVM using `class.getResource("/audio")` or `class.getResource("/xmlData")`

If you really do want to **unpack** the `.jar` to make the folders available, then it's worth knowing that a `.jar` simply uses the `.zip` format.

There are already `Maven`, `ANT` and other build tools which unpack / move around `.zip` and `.jar` files for the purposes of project management or building.

If you want to really do it programmatically, then there are classes in the `java.util.zip` package. In fact, `java.util.jar.JarInputStream` actually extends `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream`